# How do I spy on an injected constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have a `Manager` that makes heavy use of the `serialport` module, and would like to run unit tests with a mocked-up version of serialport.  I've rewritten my manager module to exploit dependency injection:

```
// file: manager.js

function Manager(SerialPort, device, baudRate) {
  this._device = device;
  this._serialPort = new SerialPort(device, {autoOpen: false, baudRate: baudRate })
};
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
```

Now I'd like to test to see that the correct arguments are passed to the `new SerialPort()` call.  I'm stuck on how to properly stub/mock the constructor.  Here's what I have so far:

```
// file: manager-test.js

function MockSerialPort(device, options) {}

describe('Manager', function() {
  describe('constructor', function() {
    it('instantiates a serial port with correct baud rate', function() {
      const manager = new Manager(MockSerialPort, '/dev/tty', 9600);
      expect(<something>).to.be.calledWith('/dev/tty', {autoOpen: false, baudRate: 9600});
    });
  });
});
```

Clearly I have a couple of holes

> in my head, oops, no I mean

in my code.  What do I need to fill out this test?

#### update

As @cdhowie points out, life is easier if I can pass an instantiated SerialPort object into Manager.  Due to some misleading documentation, I didn't think that was possible with the SerialPort API, but thanks to his help, the implementation now looks like:

```
function Manager(serialPort) {
  this._serialPort = serialPort;
}
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;
```

This means that in my tests, I simply create something that looks, swims and quacks like a SerialPort object.  Stubbing and spying then becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an anonymous function that stores its arguments in the scope of the test:

```
let ctorArgs;
const manager = new Manager(function () {
    ctorArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}, '/dev/tty', 9600);

// Assert against the contents of ctorArgs
```

---

Side note: why do you pass the constructor function and arguments to `Manager` instead of just passing a constructed `SerialPort` object?  Unless `Manager` needs to create more than one object with the same arguments, it seems a bit silly to give it the burden of creating the object.

Comment: > "Why do you pass the constructor function..." The serialport API doesn't have an accessor for the device, which I need later in my Manager code.  I could do `new Manager(new SerialPort(device, ...), device)`, but it smells bad to pass the device twice.

Comment: If you're using serialport from npm, then yes, [there is an accessor](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/blob/master/lib/serialport.js#L166).

Comment: Aw heck - how did I miss that?  Then I will pass in a constructed object.  Much easier, thanks.

Comment: You missed it because serialport is not fully documented, like 90% of the stuff on npm. I usually just read the source to figure out what's available because so many modules lack any kind of useful or complete docs.